# Android Time Not Adjustable by user

Tags: java, android, time, system

I'm trying to make an incentive feature where every 3 hours you will get something free inside my app. However using the

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

You can easily get around that by just changing your androids time manually to 3 hours in the future and the game will reward you with the free feature. Is there a way to get some kind of time that isn't based off of the system time?

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of that, I don't think making a call to a server every time the user starts up the app is a good move. I would rather risk the select few pulling one over on me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the methods:

```
SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
```

They do not depend on the device clock. If for some reason you can't use them directly, at least you could use them to make a smart validation of changes in the device clock.

good luck.